# Program execution stops after catching runtime exception

Tags: java, exception

I am executing a code that throws IllegalStateException. I want to catch that exception and continue the program execution but my program stops execution when this exception is encountered.

I have tried placing `try{} catch{}` block at multiple places. Also, tried using

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() { } 
});
```

to catch this exception.

```
try {
    List<ItemStandardFields> output = response.body().getContents();
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() { } 
    });
            // some code               
}catch(Exception ex){           
    log.error(ex.getLocalizedMessage());            
}
```

Actual - My program execution stops after getting exception at output = ...getContents();
Expected - I want my program to continue execution after catching exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working! The main exception was "JsonSyntaxException" and the message was "IllegalStateException". So the code works if i catch JsonSyntaxException instead of IllegalStateException.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your code in a new thread and use the Thread class's defaultUncaughtExceptionHandler. Please check the following code.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

      Thread thread = new Thread(new MyThread());

      thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.
      UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
         public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
            log.error(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
         }
      });
      thread.start();


    }
    }

    class MyThread implements Runnable {

       public void run() {
          List<ItemStandardFields> output = response.body().getContents();
       }
    }
```

Comment: Do you know the reason why IllegalStateException cannot be handled like other exceptoins?